# MVC framework seems to suggest creating possibly hundreds of .aspx or .cshtml pages. How do I avoid this?

Tags: frameworks, mvc

So, I was playing around with MVC3.  Correct me if I'm wrong but based on all examples I've seen, it is suggested that you pretty much have a page for every model and Action from the Controller.  So for example create a pretty basic management portal for the aspnetdb database.

**Models**

UserModel
RoleModel

**Actions**

CreateUserAction
DeleteUserAction
ChangeUserAction
CreateRoleAction
DeleteRoleAction
UpdateRoleAction
AssignUserToRoleAction
AssignUsersToRoleAction
AssignUserToRoleAction
AssignUsersToRolesAction
DeleteUsersFromRoleAction
etc...

**Pages**

CreateUser.aspx or .cshtml
DeleteUser.aspx or .cshtml
ChangeUser.aspx or .cshtml
CreateRole.aspx or .cshtml
DeleteRole.aspx or .cshtml
UpdateRole.aspx or .cshtml
AssignUserToRole.aspx or .cshtml
AssignUsersToRole.aspx or .cshtml
AssignUserToRole.aspx or .cshtml
AssignUsersToRoles.aspx or .cshtml
DeleteUsersFromRole.aspx or .cshtml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is close to the truth. Full and partial views do increase in numbers rapidly as you go.

This is however much more preferable to having one single God WebForms page that takes care of everything. With time it typically turns into a giant unmanageable blurb forcing you to reenginer the thing and likely to redo the entire work. You know, we've all been there.

Here you have an option to split your presentation layer into small manageable pieces. You can develop them separately, reuse them. You can even set the OutputCache per action which provides you with a great flexibility. I personally find it awesome.

In short: it is a good thing!

Comment: @Developer Art: I've been doing MVC3 as a training item lately, and slowly I've noticed the file bloat problem. Do you have any techniques or tools to help reduce page rot?

Comment: There are areas which you can take advantage of to logically separate different modules. I personally just structure things in subfolders which works fine for me.

Comment: @Developer Art: Pat your brain for me.

Comment: Personally, I prefer file bloat to code bloat (amount of code in a single file).  I find a hierarchical folder structure very easy to navigate.  One technique I use to manage the large number of files is organizing folders by the logical area they are concerned with (users, billing, subscriptions, etc.) with subfolders for different types of classes (controllers, models, views, etc), and not the other way around (which seems more common).

Comment: @qes: That's exactly how areas work.

Comment: @Developer Art: Yes, for MVC projects.  I also extend that reasoning to shared libraries.  For example, I have no top level folders named "Repositories" or "Entities" etc. in my Core or Data projects (as seems common), but also split those up by functional areas.  I didn't want to limit the scope of my comment to only MVC projects by explicitly stating areas, but it is good to point that out (as without them it is troublesome to place views as I prefer). Of course, sometimes areas are more useful as a larger level of organization yet (e.g., admin vs. members vs. public)